# How to bind to parent DataTemplate from within an ItemsControl.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a container type control which contains a number of items.  The container control has a `DataTemplate` defined which also contains a `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` for the item.  The items however need to bind to something from the container control.  A simplified example is given below:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ContainerType}">

    <!-- Display of the container stuff-->

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Item}">

                  <!-- Display of the item stuff -->
                  <ComboBox Text="Choose a container-level option..."
                            ItemsSource="{WHAT GOES HERE?}"/>

                </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

      </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

How to I bind something at the item level back up to the container level?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `RelativeSource` binding

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                  AncestorType={x:Type local:MyContainerControl}}}"/>
```

What you use for your binding path depends on where the collection is located. If it is located as a `DependencyProperty` on `MyContainerControl`, then the above binding works fine. If it is located in the `DataContext` of `MyContainerControl`, then you'll need to set the binding path to `DataContext.SomeCollection`

Comment: The collection is a property in the DataContext of the ContainerType DataTemplate so I tried `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ContainerType}}, Path=DataContext.AvailableJobs}`.  Also tried the form above but neither worked...

Comment: @BrianTriplett Remove the `FindAncestor,` from your binding

Comment: sorry but still not displaying the collection in the ComboBox.  When you say `MyContainerControl` are you referring to what I've called `ContainerType` in my example code or are you referring to the control that contains the DataTemplate for `ContainerType` (in this case a `ContentControl`)?

Comment: @BrianTriplett The Control that contains the DataTemplate for `ContainerType`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use TemplateBinding?

Something like:

```
{TemplateBinding YourPropertyInTheDataTemplateContext}
```

Comment: TemplateBinding only works for ControlTemplates, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a big fan of `ElementName`.  Basically you make sure you name the outer level control like : `x:Name="MainWin"` and then you can do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=DataContext.SomeCollection}"/>
```

Comment: This won't work. A DataTemplate does not get a definitive name in the visual tree such that it could be referenced via `ElementName`

Comment: I used to think so too but I assure you that I have it working in a WPF project.  Just tested it.  Are you using Silverlight?  Here's a cut/past from my actual working code:

Comment: `  <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                        <Button Command="{Binding DeleteSkillSetCommand, ElementName=MainWin}" CommandParameter="{Binding ''}" Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonStyle}" Margin="5" x:Name="DeleteSkillSet" VerticalAlignment="Center"   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <Image Source="images/RedX.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>

Comment: @BrianTriplett  I re-read your response.  You are correct that the DataTemplate does not get a name in the element tree, but Bindings in the DataTemplate can reference elements by name in the visual tree outside of the template.  Just not the other way around since the DataTemplate is not an actual element but a factory.

Comment: also, just my additional $0.02.  The RelativeResource seems cleaner and the ElementName maybe more of a quick hack, but it is quick and does work.