# Binding SelectedItem in comobox with current ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

So what I am trying to achieve is to bind the current item from the ItemsSource to the SelectedItem in a Comobox I hope the following (A simplified example)  code would demonstrate what I want.

```
public class book : INotifyPropertyChanged{
private string _title;
private string _author;

public book(){
    this.Title = "";
    this.
}
public string Title{
    get{return _title;}
    set{
        _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");

    }
}
public string Author{
    get{return _author;}
    set{
        _author = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Author");
    }
}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

The ThisViewModel.cs Code:

```
public class ThisViewModel{
    private ObservableCollection<Book> _book;
    private List<Book> _existedBooks;
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Book{
        get{return _book;}
        set{_book = value;}
    }

    public ThisViewModel(){
        Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
        Books.Add(new Book())
    }
    public List<Book> ExistedBooks{
        get{return _existedBooks;}
        set{_existedBooks = value;}
    }
}
```

The code-behind of the ThisView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ThisView{
    public ThisView(){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ThisViewModel();

    }
}
```

The XAML code ThisView.xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Book}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExistedBooks}"  
            DisplayMemberPath="Title"
            SelectedItem="{Binding <HERE IS MY PROBLEM>}"
            ></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I bind the selectedItem (one of the existedBooks) to the ItemsControl current Item (Book).

Hope I made my point clear enough.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to parent DataTemplate from within an ItemsControl.ItemTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184972/how-to-bind-to-parent-datatemplate-from-within-an-itemscontrol-itemtemplate)

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the same `Book` object to both collections for this to work:

```
public ThisViewModel()
{
    Book = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
    ExistedBooks = new List<Book>();

    Book bookA = new Book() { Title = "Title A" };
    Book.Add(bookA);
    ExistedBooks.Add(bookA);
}
```

Then you can bind the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox to the current item in the ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Book}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ExistedBooks, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}"
                               DisplayMemberPath="Title" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But what I really need to bind(fill) a `Book` object from the `Books` collection to a `Book` object from the `ExistedBooks` collection.

Comment: You can't add objects to collections in XAML. You should do this in the view model. XAML is a *markup* language. Besides this the application logic should be implemented in the view model. That's one of the cornerstones of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: You answer says if I have a book in the `ExistedBooks` with title  _Title A_ and I selected it, while the current item in the `Book` list has the title _Title B_, if I break at this point I _TItle B_ will become _Title A_, or is this impossible ?

Comment: As mentioned you should add the same Book object to both collections. Just because two books have the same title, they don't refer to the same Book object in memory.